# LINQ Logic, Navigating to the ApplicationUser Identity table, roles and a business object called project

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to grab a list of ApplicationUsers that have role type of 'Project_Manager' and that are not assigned to a projectId I pass in.  I've tried to write this several different ways but the outcome is not what I'd expect.  Any suggestions with my logic?

```
var pmNotAssigned = 
    (from p in db.Project
     from u in p.Users
     where p.ProjectId != projectId && 
         u.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == db.Roles.FirstOrDefault(rr => rr.Name == "Project_Manager").Id)
     select u)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me immediately.  It what way is the outcome not what you expect?

Comment: Its returning a list of users that have a role of "Project_Manager" but the '!=' where clause is not working.  I have a list of pm users assigned to the project and I'd like to have a list of users not assigned so that I can add them to a multiselect.  Right now, I have 2 lists of PM's.  The only difference between the two queries is the '!=' vs '=='.  Is the '!' in the wrong spot?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my guess is that there is some overlap of users between your projects.  I assume your data looks something like this:

- Project1

  - User1
  - User2
- Project2

  - User1
  - User3

Using this sample data, if you pass project id 1 to your method then your current query will ignore Project1, not all users of project 1.  So it would return User1 and User3 but you don't want User1.

Give this a try instead:

```
var pmNotAssigned = 
    db.Users
    .Where(user =>
        // List of project's users does not contain this user.
        db.Project
            .First(p => p.ProjectId == projectId)
            .Users
            .All(projectUser => projectUser.Id != user.UserId) &&
        // List of this user's roles contains the 'Project_Manager' role.
        user.Roles
            .Any(r => r.RoleId == db.Roles.FirstOrDefault(rr => rr.Name == "Project_Manager").Id));
```

Comment: It Bawked at '.First' so I tried FirstOrDefault but It didn't produce a result :(

Comment: Hard to say what the problem might be without more information.  Did you get an exception?  If so what was it.